# What is a sentence with initials in alphabetical order called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Given a sentence such as "Can I please return these violins?"

The initials of this sentence read CIPRTV.

Is there a single word that can describe a sentence in which the initials are in alphabetical order?

I'd like to be able to say "The above sentence is a(n) _____"

A phrase would be acceptable but I would be happier with a single word if one exists.

Comment: @Lawrence In an acrostic, the initials are supposed to spell something meaningful. I don't think CIPRTV qualifies as something meaningful.

Comment: Following @Lawrence's link, I devise that _abecedarius_ is a bit closer to the mark. However that seems to require that the entire alphabet is accounted for. I only require that all initials are in alphabetical order, not that the entire alphabet is present.

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a [panalphabetic window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panalphabetic_window) which contains every letter in the alphabet at least once and in order. So you can use panalphabetic initialism. But of course it's a neologism. However after visiting related wikipedia pages I am quite certain that such a word does not exist.

Comment: I like your angle on that. I suppose taking your answer and guiding it more towards the specific requirements of the question would involve dropping the 'pan' prefix, as it does not require every letter in the alphabet. It feels like 'alphabetic initialism' is as close as we may get. This probably leads us onto another question of "If I said the above sentence is an alphabetic initialism, what would you understand from that?"

Comment: @DarrenH that's quite problematic, without any context I would know exactly what it should mean.